# Query certain field according to condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here's the schema of the data that I'm working with :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    field1 : {
        subField1: String,
        subField2: String
    },
    field2 : {
        subField1: String,
        subField2: String
    }
}
```

I want to check if field1.subField1 or field2.subField1 are equal to some value and then accordingly retrieve other field. For example, if field1.subField1 is equal to the value that I want to search then I want to get value of field2 and vice versa. I tried using `$elemMatch` but couldn't figure out proper solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, perhaps a more direct than my other answer....

Again assuming the following document, and you wish to find where field1 is "CCC"...

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    field1 : {
        subField1: "AAA",
        subField2: "BBB"
    },
    field2 : {
        subField1: "CCC",
        subField2: "DDD"
    }
}
```

... here is the aggregation...

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        $project:
        {
            desiredValue:
            {
                $switch:
                {
                    branches:
                    [
                        {
                            case: { $eq: [ "$field1.subField1", "CCC" ] },
                            then: "$field1.subField2"
                        },
                        {
                            case: { $eq: [ "$field2.subField1", "CCC" ] },
                            then: "$field2.subField2"
                        }
                    ],
                    default: null
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

This is a single stage aggregation with a switch statement comparing the fields and selecting the output.

Comment: Very nice and easy. Just curious, is there a way to achieve this dynamically where the key names are unknown?

Comment: This is a really simple way of achieving the result that I wanted. Is there a way to just get the array of values instead of assigning each value (object) to propetry like desiredValue ?

Comment: Use `$group` with `null` as `_id` and use `$push` or `$addToSet` as required where the `$switch` example privided by @berrypicker is embedded.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: "$_id",
            array1: { $push: "$field1" },
            array2: { $push: "$field2" },
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: 1,
            arrayConcat: { $concatArrays: [ "$array1", "$array2" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$arrayConcat"
    },
    {
        $match: { "arrayConcat.subField1": "CCC" }
    },
    {
        $project: { desiredValue: "$arrayConcat.subField2"}
    }
])
```

### Explanation:

Assuming the following document...

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    field1 : {
        subField1: "AAA",
        subField2: "BBB"
    },
    field2 : {
        subField1: "CCC",
        subField2: "DDD"
    }
}
```

... and assuming you wish to find value "DDD" from key "CCC"...

1. Perform an aggregation on the collection.
2. Group by _id so the data is isolated per record.  This grouping will
   convert objects "field1" and "field2" into arrays using $push.
3. Use $project to concatenate the two arrays together so they share
   the same array object.
4. Unwind the array object so the fields are now in the same position
   but separated per document.
5. Match on the desired query field value - example shows "CCC".
   Project the desired output field - example shows field name
   "desiredValue".

### Notes:

This would be easier if you use the attribute pattern to begin with.  See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern.

Comment: Thanks @barrypicker. Your explanation was really helpful.